# Can you add HTML to react-tippy tooltip

Tags: reactjs, react-tippy

I want to add a  to a react-tippy tooltip.
Is it possible?
I only get it to show `[object Object]`

Look at `title` bellow

```
                    <Tooltip
                        // title={this.renderTicks(idx, row)}
                        title={<div>
                            <h4>Hello</h4>
                            <span>This is a span</span>
                        </div>}
                        position="right"
                        trigger="click"
                        theme="light"
                        arrow="true"
                        arrowSize="big"
                        distance="3"
                        style={{fontSize:14}}
                    >
                        <div>Click Here</div>
                    </Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use it before but reading [the documentation](https://github.com/tvkhoa/react-tippy) said that you can use html props.
"Tooltip content. If you don't define html, the title will be used"

Something like this:

```
<Tooltip
  html={(
    <div>
      <h4>Hello</h4>
      <span>This is a span</span>
    </div>
  )}
>
```

Comment: I will give you the correct answer cus you need the points. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you!!! You are so kind. I'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

OK seems easy enough

instead of `title` just use 'html'

```
                <Tooltip
                    // title={this.renderTicks(idx, row)}
                    html={<div>
                        <h4>Hello</h4>
                        <span>This is a span</span>
                    </div>}
                    position="right"
                    trigger="click"
                    theme="light"
                    arrow="true"
                    arrowSize="big"
                    distance="3"
                    style={{fontSize:14}}
                >
                    <div>Click Here</div>
                </Tooltip>
```